# Install TensorFlow-0.9.0rc0 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) gets not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, tensorflow

While this seems to be a dupe, I cannot resolve, I have a fully current 14.04 Ubuntu and updated PIP yet I am getting, wondering if it is related to being a new release of tensorflow?:

```
tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

in response to:

```
 sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Wondering if there is a pip issue? or a wheel issue? I am running a pretty extensive amount if python software all installed fine with pip... So It seems unique to TensorFlow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Python 2 it works for me (on Ubuntu 14.04).

```
sudo pip2 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

To use it with Python 3.4, use this:

```
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

More info: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

Comment: seems the pip2 vs pip is needed on my system...! Thanks!